# Is my regex correct? ^(?!_|[0-9])(?!.*__)[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?<!_)$

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex:

```
^(?!_|[0-9])(?!.*__)[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?<!_)$
```

This is what i want to achieve:

1. can not start with number or underscore,
2. consecutive underscore is not allowed
3. only letter, number and underscore are allowed
4. can not end with underscore

Does my regex works per my requirement? i did a research, says that my regex has negative lookhehind, and javascript does not support it. Please also help me in creating equivalent to my regex that support javascript.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you know about the many "regex testing" sites, is this the research you did (e.g. https://regex101.com/). And finally, more specific questions are better. Have your found a string which incorrectly matches? It would be better to ask "this is my regex. It doesn;t work on ABC. Why not?"

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) as well as [Why is "Is this correct?" an off topic question, and what should I ask instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359466)

Comment: Also, I'm confused - your title asks about whether your existing regex is correct, and the last line asks about how to implement this in JavaScript. Which are you asking about - whether this is correct, or how to fix it? Either way, Stack Overflow is neither a free code-testing service nor a free code-conversion service. Can you [edit] to clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with for the 4 requirements you listed:

```
^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9]*_[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

I am not sure what you are doing with your regex, but to me it does not look valid. If you want to test it out for yourself, try regex101.com

Comment: This doesn't work either. Doesn't even match `hello_123abc` https://regexr.com/4ppes

Comment: Try now, forgot the * at the end

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern fulfills your requirements. Instead of using negative lookbehind for a `_`, match `[A-Za-z0-9]` at the end (the character set without a `_`):

```
^(?!_|[0-9])(?!.*__)[A-Za-z0-9_]*[A-Za-z0-9]$
```

You can also simplify `[A-Za-z0-9_]` to `\w`, `[0-9]` to `\d`, use the case-insensitive flag instead of repeating `a-zA-Z`, and combine the initial negative lookaheads if you wish:

```
/^(?![_\d]|.*__)\w*[a-z\d]$/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/NVPT7T/1

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular expression that tests true for the cases that you don't want and then negate the result.

Cases you don't want:

1. Starts with number or underscore: `^[0-9_]`
2. Consecutive underscores: `__`
3. Something else than a letter, number or underscore: `[^0-9a-z_]`
4. Ends with underscore: `_$`

Finally, join all of them with ORs `|`, giving:

```
^[0-9_]|_$|__|[^0-9a-z_]
```

And then negate the test:

```
!/^[0-9_]|_$|__|[^0-9a-z_]/gi.test('your string here')
```

See the tests here:
https://regex101.com/r/nEdwPV/1